# Notification is triggered again and again

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am creating a notification on a activity called Mainmenu using alarm here is code

`Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, SyncService.class);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainMenu.this, 1, myIntent,0);
 Calendar calforAlram = Calendar.getInstance();
 calforAlram.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
 calforAlram.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 46);
 calforAlram.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calforAlram.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);`

On notification received , on click of the notification i have to open the same `Mainmenu` activity.

Problem: again one more notification is generated , again click on notification again Mainmenu activity will open and continues

Here is Notification code

```
NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MAFLogonActivity.class);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle("XXXXXXXX")
            .setContentText("Please sync data.").setAutoCancel(true);
    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 1, intent1, 0);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);
    Log.d("On service", "Alarms set for everyday 2 pm.");
    mManager.notify(0, notification.build());
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
```

Comment: Did you consider using `IntentService`? It will finish itself when the work is done then not be called again until is triggered again.

Comment: Did you used my solution ?

Comment: yes it worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the application has started from push notification or normal.

How to do this.

**Notification generate code**

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MAFLogonActivity.class);
intent1.putExtra("isFromNotification", true);
```

**onCreate()** of **MAFLogonActivity.java**

```
boolean isFromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isFromNotification", false);

if(!isFromNotification){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, SyncService.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainMenu.this, 1, myIntent, 0);
        Calendar calforAlram = Calendar.getInstance();
        calforAlram.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        calforAlram.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 46);
        calforAlram.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calforAlram.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
 }
```

Hope this would help you.